# VBA for updating Powerpoint Links

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've got some vba code to update links in powerpoint.  For some of the links it works perfectly and for some it just does not want to update.
I did notice that the links update if it is an excel worksheet but if the link is a chart in excel it does not want to update:

```
Sub ul()
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape

Dim oldString As String
oldString = "C:\Users\username\Downloads\dir\Mar Apr 2014\"
Dim newString As String
newString = "C:\Users\newusername\Downloads\dir\Jan Feb 2015\"

For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
            With pptShape.LinkFormat
                If InStr(1, UCase(.SourceFullName), UCase(oldString)) Then
                    .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, oldString, newString)
                End If
            End With
        End If
    DoEvents
    Next pptShape
DoEvents
Next pptSlide
End Sub
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to expand your If query like

```
If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Or 
   pptShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or pptShape.Type = msoChart Then
```

Comment: No it is not solving the problem, I even tried different types from this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.type%28v=office.14%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Show us some examples of what the .SourceFullname looks like for the links that do and don't work.